# ASP.NET File.Exists returns false when file exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, permissions

File.Exists is returning false when the file actually exists.

I know it would return false if there's no read permissions, but I can't seem to get it right.

More info:

My FTP directory is organized like so:

```
Root

    ImageSite

        ImageDirectory

    MySite

        My .aspx.cs File that's calling File.Exists()
```

I tried uploading the .aspx.cs file with the same ftp user account as ImageSite & ImageDirectory. Didn't help.

I also tried replacing forward slashes with back slashes, just to be sure.

Here's my code - I hard-coded the file path to the complete ftp path of the image directory.

```
        string serverUrl =@"\\fs4-n01\blah\blah\blah\ImageSite.com\web\content\Images\" + product.ImageUrl;
        bool exists = File.Exists(serverUrl);
```

I also thought of impersonation. I am already using one identity impersonation in my web.config and it didn't seem to let me use both, so I placed this one under the subdirectory where my code file is, under  tag. But it didn't seem to do it. (Either way, the owner of the file is the same as the image directory, as I mentioned.)

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: by the url it looks like you are using samba (file sharing), not ftp.  Is that correct?  Can you actually open the file in explorer from the path in your code?  Also is your code running under a different user (maybe that user can't access that fileshare)?

Comment: Does that account that the site runs under (see the application pool identity) have permissions to read the directory?

Comment: Not sure, I definitely access it via FTP. I got that URL from using File.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath("~"))...

Comment: You should ask for you provider what's the path to access the file system, as the disks may be mounted on a given configuration.

Comment: @Oded  how do I set those permissions? I thought by having the owner of my code files and the image directories as the same, there wouldn't be a permission issue.

Comment: Code owner is one thing. I am talking about the account that the site runs as.

Comment: I'm confused. This is a shared hosting environment. How/where would I set/view the site permissions? (Impersonation?)

Comment: I called my hosting provider (Rackspace) and was told the way .NET works is you cannot access files beyond the content directory for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called my hosting provider (Rackspace) and was told the way .NET works is you cannot access files beyond the content directory for security reasons. (For ASP classic sites, it does let you, as of now.)

Comment: Can you provide any documentation to back up this information?

Comment: @RyanGates to clarify, this is a Rackspace-specific limitation for cloud-site environments.